# How to execute command in Powershell 6 (core) from within Powershell 5?

Tags: powershell

I wish to run the following command from within Powershell 5 but make it execute with Powershell 6:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major
```

How can this be done?

The expected return value from the command should be '6'.

I am getting this:

```
pwsh -command "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major"

System.Collections.Hashtable.PSVersion.Major : The term 'System.Collections.Hashtable.PSVersion.Major' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ System.Collections.Hashtable.PSVersion.Major
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.Collections.\u2026ble.PSVersion.Major:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the double-quotes.  PowerShell 5 is using string interpolation on the string before passing  it to `pwsh`.  So, what you see as:

`pwsh -command "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major"`

Is actually passed as:

`pwsh -command "System.Collections.Hashtable.PSVersion.Major.PSVersion.Major"`

The solution is to use single quotes (which 'switches off' interpolation):

`pwsh -command '$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major'`